# three.js particle geometry in particle system

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am using a standard system of particles in three.js, but I do not know whether it is possible instead to use any geometry of the particles, such as boxing or plane.
I'm trying to make the particles from falling bullets, but the problem is that all the particles look at me and do not get it, that is, I can not set the angle of rotation of the particle, and in which direction to look.

Is it possible to three.js use geometry instead of a particle?

Answer (score 0):

I think particles inside three.js are points sprites.
We have geometry filled with points, each point have texture and inside the shader point is covered with that texture. (point sprites)

Problems with them:

- They always look at us.
- Rotating them is problematic. (we can only try to manipulate texture coordinates - uvs)
- Every point (for example P = (x,y) ) must be inside visible space. (clip space?) Size (point size) doesn't matter. Point will be simply not displayed if his x,y is outside clipspace. Point sprites aren't recommended for large particles.

You can try to write own emitter basing on three.js particles emitter or try to find something like that somewhere. (I didn't find anything like that)